# can we register entity to global store in ngrx? is that possible?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

It would be nice if we entity in our global store?

I have some crud operations, which are very easily done using @ngrx/entity and I want to have it in root-store.

I have tried creating an entity, but schematics did it for forFeature().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NgRx Entity is basically a Dictionary with matching NgRx operators to update/read.
You can always hold an Entity Object in any store that can store a string for example. You can do so by extending the Store if you just need one Entity Object

```js
export interface State extends EntityState<User> {
    ...
}
```

or you can create Entity Objects in the Store like

```js
export interface State {
  users: EntityState<User>;
  books: EntityState<Book>;
}
```

Both ways you can work with adapters. For the extend version pass the whole `State` to the adapter. For the second approach pass the users property to the adapter method and set the result as new value for that property in the state.

**Edit**
To update the Entity object a adapter is used. Create an adapter and use it in the reducers. A lot more infos about it and code examples can be found at https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter

```js
// adapter definition
export const userAdapter: EntityAdapter<User> = createEntityAdapter<User>();

// reducer call for extended state / first version
on(UserActions.setUsers, (state, { users }): State => userAdapter.setAll(users, state)),
```

Comment: can you please tell me What do you mean by parsing the Whole state for an extended version? and also can you provide any examples in stackBlitz?